# GMaps autocomplete - how to freeze ac results on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I use the following GMaps Code for autocomplete. With typing text into the input-field an pressing return I normally receive I new ac-result. (marker, info_windows, geo-infomations) When I type another text I receive a new marker and the old marker is deleted.
How can I "freeze" the old marker with the old info-window on the map, when I do a new request? Thanks a lot

//Autocomplete

```
enter code here//Autocomplete

var acOptions = {
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'}

};
var autocomplete = 
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'),acOptions);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds',map);
var ac_iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var ac_image = 
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png',
   new google.maps.Size(32,32),
   new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   new google.maps.Point(0,32));

var ac_shadow = 
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55s.png',
   new google.maps.Size(45,35),
   new google.maps.Point(0,0),
   new google.maps.Point(0,32));


var ac_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   icon: ac_image,
   shadow: ac_shadow

 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete,'place_changed',function(){
   ac_iw.close();
   var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   if(place.geometry.viewport){
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
   }
    else{
       map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
       map.setZoom(10);
   }

 ac_marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
 ac_iw.setContent('<strong>' + place.name + 
    '</strong><br/>' + place.formatted_address +
 '<br/>tel.: ' + place.formatted_phone_number);
   ac_iw.open(map,ac_marker);
  google.maps.event.addListener(ac_marker,'click',function(){
    ac_iw.open(map,ac_marker);
  });

  });

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to

- move the marker creation code inside the autoComplete 'place_changed' handler to create a new marker for each autocompletion
- move the ac_iw.setContent code inside the ac_marker, 'click' handler to repopulate the infoWindow every time a marker is clicked.
- avoid .`markerImage()` which is now deprecated

So, for the most part, it's just a question of shuffling things round.

```
var acOptions = {
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'}
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), acOptions);
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var ac_iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker_options = {
    map: map,
    icon: {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(32,32),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,32)
    },
    shadow: {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon55s.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(45,35),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,32)
    }
};

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    ac_iw.close();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if(place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(10);
    }
    var ac_marker = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);
    ac_marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    google.maps.event.addListener(ac_marker, 'click', function() {
        ac_iw.setContent('<strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br/>' + place.formatted_address + '<br/>tel.: ' + place.formatted_phone_number);
        ac_iw.open(map, this);
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(ac_marker, 'click');
});
```

*untested - may need debugging*

Comment: OK, it works, so I don't understand why the info-window automatically opens after the place_changed event. I mean shouldn't it be triggered by the click event??

Comment: The reason *why* it opens automatically is that's the behaviour of the original code in the question. What causes it to open automatically (with the correct content) is the line `google.maps.event.trigger(ac_marker, 'click');`.

Comment: So I have a click-event here without triggering it by a 'click'!?

Comment: Essentially yes. This is the way to simulate an event programatically and cause any attached handlers to fire, as if caused by genuine event - in this case a click event. `.trigger()` is used here to avoid repetition of the code in the click handler. It's much simpler to `.trigger()` the event and cause the handler to fire. Get it?

Comment: O.K. I understand that you use trigger() for making things easier, however I mean it's a fact that the opening of the window is triggered by 'place_changed' and not 'click'. So why does it open? (the second anonymus function (click-event) within in the the first one (listener: 'place_change') is also not affected by 'place_change' but by 'click' obviously!)

Comment: Remember I've only rearranged your original code, I didn't write it from scratch, and I've not seen it working. The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) says of the `place-changed` event, "this event is fired when a PlaceResult is made available for a Place the user has selected".

Comment: I mean it's just one little thing that I don't understand! You said that I should put the new marker object into the first anonymous function. Now the information of that marker, selected by a place-changed event, is conserved and the marker "freezes" on the map. Now I have to put the information of the info-window into the second anonymous function, otherwise the result would be that every maker has the same info-window output of the current marker. (second closure!!) Now I have the information of the info-window encapsulted but I still don't understand that machenism of that trigger-object!

Comment: Are you saying (a) the infowindow opens automatically and  don't want it to, or (b) the infoWindow doesn't open automatically and you want it to?

Comment: Combination of (a) and (b) : The info-window opens automatically and I want it to. I mean I just learn it by heart that I use `google.maps.event.trigger(ac_marker, 'click');` for automatically opening the infowindow!!

Comment: OK, I understand but I can't really help any more because I know only about the code in the question. I've not seen the entire web page.